# Specifying the correct IAM permission for access to multiple s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to give users read/write/list permissions to certain buckets and my IAM policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::kl-bucket1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::kl-bucket2",
                "arn:aws:s3:::kl-bucket3",
                "arn:aws:s3:::kl-bucket4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::kl-bucket3",
                "arn:aws:s3:::kl-bucket4"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to write to bucket4 I get an 403 error, however if I give full permission like below then I am able to write to bucket4.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the issue?

P.S. While this issue is similar to [S3: How to grant access to multiple buckets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744753/s3-how-to-grant-access-to-multiple-buckets) the actual problem is different.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I also setting the Access control after PutObject, while the IAM policy was setting that permission.
[@Asarluhi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255099/aws-s3-iam-policy-for-read-and-write-permissions-on-a-single-bucket?answertab=active#tab-top)'s answer helped.
Have modified the Action to:

```
"Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
```