# How do I create an amazon S3 policy that prevents deleting buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I create an amazon S3 policy that prevents deleting buckets?
Currently I have this Json. But I want to disable the possibility of deleting buckets.

How do I do that?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

References:

[S3: How to grant access to multiple buckets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744753/s3-how-to-grant-access-to-multiple-buckets?rq=1)

[s3 Policy has invalid action - s3:ListAllMyBuckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643058/s3-policy-has-invalid-action-s3listallmybuckets?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this policy:

```json
{
  "Id": "Policy1654447414913",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1654447407349",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-example-bucket",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Don't forget to attach it to the bucket.

The policy was generated with [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html).

Comment: I didnt know about the policy generator, hopefully it can also help others. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

S3 buckets can only be deleted if they're empty so what you're wanting may be redundant depending on your use-case.

Comment: I tried deleting a bucket with files and it worked. How do you prevent that?

Comment: I'm not sure how you've done this as it's in the documentation that you can't delete a bucket with objects in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/delete-bucket.html